# Swift2 send POST request

Tags: post, swift2, request

I want to use Swift 2 to send a POST request to my demo service.
I've tested my demo service with command `curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"` and it works successfully(the service outputs a message after receiving a POST request).
However when I use Swift2, nothing happened. Here is my Swift code:

```
let urlAddress : String = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
let url = NSURL(string: urlAddress)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
task.resume()
```

Note: these code run in an `exec` application, not a normal application with UI or Games.

Any suggestion is thankful!

Comment: I copied these code into a demo application, under a UIButton, and it works! So I wonder whether I set something wrong. I'm a new for Swift2 and iOS

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are sending a POST request fine, but won't know that because in general, a request that you send returns an error, response and some data in return. In your case you are just sending a request, not asking for a response. Look at the code below. Here I have a data task that has a completion handler, that helps you get response,data and error.

```
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Post Request successful")
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I tried like this:  let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, resp, err -> Void in
        let httpResp = resp as! NSHTTPURLResponse!
        print(httpResp)
    })  but nothing happened

Comment: Okay now I am starting to think that you are just testing your request. What I mean is that maybe you have not configured your server/ loaded it with data. Hence, I have edited above code, try it, and if you can print "Post request successful" I would say you're fine.